# Python: Why is FFT giving different results for the same data?

Tags: python, data-science, fft, autocorrelation

I have a datafile named 'yclip.txt' which is just a 1-column data. The program finds the the gradient of the autocorrelation function (here, dacf) of this data using the function `ps.acf_dacf()`. It then computes the FFT of dacf which gives the ADP.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq
import pulsar as ps

#Load data
data = pd.read_csv('yclip.txt', header = None)
data = np.array(data)
acf, dacf = ps.acf_dacf(data)
n = len(dacf)

#Fourier transform of dacf
adp = np.fft.fft(dacf)
adp = (np.abs(adp[:n//2]))**2

adp = adp/np.max(adp)                       #Normalizing

adpfreq = fftfreq(n, 0.65536)[:n//2]        #Frequency domain

#Plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax[0].plot(dacf)
ax[0].set_xlabel("Lags")
ax[0].set_ylabel("d/dt(ACF)")
ax[0].set_title("d/dt(ACF)")
ax[1].plot(adpfreq, adp)
ax[1].set_xlabel("Frequency (kHz)")
ax[1].set_ylabel("Power") 
ax[1].set_title("ADP")
plt.suptitle("When dacf is calculated and then fft is taken")
plt.show()
```

The plots of the dacf and ADP:
[image]
This ADP is wrong as there should be peak in the zero-component frequency as it is an FFT. Now the weird part is, if we save the array dacf as a txt file, load that txt file into python without making any changes, and then find the FFT, the ADP it outputs is different as given below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq
import pulsar as ps

#loading dacf from txt
dacf = pd.read_csv('dacf.txt', header = None)
dacf = np.array(dacf)
n = len(dacf)

#Fourier transform of dacf
adp = np.fft.fft(dacf)
adp = (np.abs(adp[:n//2]))**2
adpy = adp/np.max(adp)                           #Normalizing

adpfreq = np.fft.fftfreq(n, 0.65536)[:n//2]      #Frequency domain

#Plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax[0].plot(dacf)
ax[0].set_xlabel("Lags")
ax[0].set_ylabel("d/dt(ACF)")
ax[0].set_title("d/dt(ACF)")
ax[1].plot(adpfreq, adp)
ax[1].set_xlabel("Frequency (kHz)")
ax[1].set_ylabel("Power") 
ax[1].set_title("ADP")
plt.suptitle("When the same dacf is saved, loaded and then fft is taken")
plt.show()
```

[image]

The dacf is same in both the cases but the ADP changes which I think is depending on how the data reached the FFT.

Here is the function `ps.acf_dacf()`:

```
def acf_dacf(y):

  if np.any(y != y[0]):
    yacf = acf(y, nlags = len(y))
    dyacf = np.gradient(yacf)
  else:
    yacf = np.ones(len(y))
    dyacf = np.zeros(len(y))

  return yacf, dyacf
```

Can someone explain what's going on here?

I tried flattening the array, checked if there is any standard deviation in both dacfs. But no good and the standard deviation is the same in both the cases. Both numpy and scipy were used but gave the same results.

Comment: I'm stumped about your question; my best guess is it has something to do with rounding that happens when writing or reading the txt file. One concern: Your `dacf` "waveform" has no continuity between the last and first samples, so you might want to apply some window (Hanning/Hamming/Blackmann/...) before taking the FFT, unless you want the discontinuity in the periodic extension of the signal to dominate the FFT.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks for the reply. Rounding does not take place as the mean and std of both the `dacf`s are equal upto the full 18 decimals. Also, the ACF should not be windowed for this task but it doesn't matter as the second ADP is the desired one. But for some reason it is not returned in the first code.

Comment: In the first bit of code you have `adp = (np.abs(adp[:n//2]))`, in the second one you have `adp = (np.abs(adp[:n//2]))**2`. These are obviously not the same.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for showing the mistake. Though that doesn't the problem coz the code originally had the `**2`. I guess I accidentally erased it while copying.  I've fixed the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Looks like `np.fft.fft()` requires the data to be in certain formats. In order to get the second ADP plot (the correct one with a peak at 0-frequency) without saving the `dacf` as a txt file, I just used `dacf = pandas.DataFrame(dacf)` before appying FFT.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. Converting to a Pandas dataframe shouldn't change the data.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think the same. It should not do anything to the data. I guess FFT has some unseen bugs coz now I think both the plots are wrong. We are still trying to find a solution.

Comment: No, `fft` is not buggy. It’s used by millions of people every day. I would start by comparing the data read in from the text file to the same array in the other code, numerically. It is likely that that is where the difference is. Maybe a difference in precision, or in type, maybe one is complex and the other real, could be anything.